# How to Add More Complex Powershell Commands to Pipeline

Tags: c#, powershell

I can't seem to run a command like this one...

```
pshell.AddCommand("(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection(" + strShare + ")");
```

...without getting an error saying that it cannot find the module.  It's expecting me to use something like

```
pshell.AddCommand("New-Object");
pshell.AddArgument("-ComObject");
pshell.Invoke();
```

How can I use that format with a command like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [AddScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd182436%28v=vs.85%29.ASPX) instead.

```
      PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create().AddScript(String.Format("(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection(\"{0}\")",strShare ));
```

Comment: Tried that, just tried it again. It gives me System.Management.Automation.ParseException with a bunch of comments about "unexpected token". I know the command works at the powershell command line.

Comment: fixed quotes.  sorry about that

Comment: My bad, another set of escaped quotes was needed.

Comment: Here's what I did instead, not sure if this could be written better:

PowerShell pshell = PowerShell.Create().AddScript(String.Format("(New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).AddWindowsPrinterConnection(\"{0}\")", strShare));